# MySQL Datetime showing incorrect time. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datetime

I added to my MySQL table a column called "registerdate", the datatype of this column is Datetime (I tried also TIMESTAMP) and in DEFAULT I have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

The datetime comes automatically after registration, its showing the correct day month and year but its showing incorrect hour (-10 hours).
I hope someone knows how to fix it, thanks for helping.

Comment: Which timezone are you saving data in?

Comment: I think its PDT – Pacific Daylight Time but I dont know how to change it because its not my timezone..

Comment: You might have to handle conversions. Which timezone is your user viewing the data (UTC / Local) - this is not straightforward if you allow the user to open the Application in Multiple TimeZones. Make sure you save data in UTC in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL documentation on `TimeStamp` (emphasis mine):

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (**This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.**) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: this might not actually be a problem - as pointed out in the comments, what happens if somebody tried to access the site from a different timezone to yours? Better to store as UTC and then do the time conversion on the connection. Read the link in my answer, and read this as well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you save the data into database, try to save with `Culture Info` like below

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;      
// CultureInfo for German in Germany.
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", ci));
```